# how to search word in txt file using mmap

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, mmap

I have been searching word from text file. When l, which is already saved in task1.txt file, it should print word or bytes value.

```
import mmap
l="communication"
paste=bytes(l,'utf-8')
with open("task1.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file_obj:
     with mmap.mmap(file_obj.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mmap_obj:
         for word in iter(mmap_obj.readline, b""):
             if word==paste:
                 print(word)
```

Comment: Can you please add the output you get with this code.

Comment: Why are you even bothering to `mmap` a file if you're only going to use the standard file method `readline` on it?